# Difference between residual plots in plot(gam.object) and crplots(model)?

Tags: r, residuals, generalized-additive-model, mgcv, car

Both `plot(gam.object)`(regardless of whether in `mgcv` or `gam`)  and `car::crplots(model)` plot the partial residuals of a predictor and the corresponding non-parametric smoother.

True or False?

If False, what then is the difference between both outputs?

The only difference/benefit I can see in plotting the gam.object is that a wider range of smoothers with more specifications (e.g. df, smoothing parameter) can be used.

Would be grateful for any insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both output the same partial residuals. The standard models that `mgcv::gam()` fits are basically GLMs but fitted with a penalized likelihood approach rather than a pure maximum likelihood approach, both via a IRLS algorithm.

The `car::crPlots()` approach only works because `mgcv::gam()` returns an object that inherits from class `"glm"` and `car::crPlots()` has a method for `"glm"` objects. Although I haven't tried it, I would expect `car::crPlots()` to fail when presented with `by` variable splines, 2d splines, and models where there are more than one linear predictor (families `ziplss()`, `gaulss()` and `gevlss()` for example, that are specific to `mgcv::gam()`.

Hence the benefit is not just restricted to the types of smoother that one can employ in fitting the model: the functionality in `plot.gam` is superior to that of `crPlots` because it was specifically designed to work with all the kinds of models that can be fitted using **mgcv**.